# Which Activation function use for 0 to 9

Tags: neural-network

I am trying to implement a picture recognizing neural net,
I am facing a problem...

When I use sigmoid function I get nice results but they are between 0 and 1. I need to get results between 0 and 9,

When I use linear activation function the numbers get very big early on resulting in `Infinity` and `NaN` in javascript.

When I use SoftPlus the numbers gets very tiny resulting in `NaN` ... what activation function should I use?

Comment: btw I am having 252 neurons on input layer, 10 and 10 on hidden layer and 1 on output layer

Answer (score 1):

You have to normalize your output in the [0, 9] range (assuming a continuous output) so you get a normalized output in the [0, 1] range, and then just use a sigmoid activation.

If instead you want a discrete output from 0 to 9 (integers), then that is a classification problem and you should use a softmax activation.

Answer (score 0):

I see you're using Javascript. I have built a javascript neural network library which is highly customisable. Check it out [here](https://github.com/wagenaartje/neataptic). It has different built-in activation functions listed [here](https://github.com/wagenaartje/neataptic/wiki/Activation), however they are very easy to to modify!

So the logistic function is written like this:

```
  LOGISTIC : function(x, derivate) {
    if (!derivate)
      return 1 / (1 + Math.exp(-x));
    var fx = Activation.LOGISTIC(x);
    return fx * (1 - fx);
  },
```

So if you want your output to be between 0 and 9, you could create a customised logistic activation function:

```
  CUSTOM_LOGISTIC : function(x, derivate) {
    if (!derivate)
      return 1 / (1 + Math.exp(-x)) * 9;
    var fx = Activation.CUSTOM_LOGISTIC(x);
    return fx * (1 - fx);
  },
```

And assign this activation function to just your output neurons/nodes.